# Why does my file info go missing when i use BufferedReader

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, filewriter

What I'm doing is that I have 3 inputs: carPlate, custId and employeeId. What I'm trying to do is update lines that I need to update based on several conditions.

This is my code to read the File, which is vehicle.csv. Basically:

```java
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(vehicle)); 
boolean vehicle_available = false;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    lineCounterVehicle++;
    String[] split_vehicle = line.split(",");
    if (split_vehicle[0].equals(carPlate) && split_vehicle[3].equals("1")){
        vehicle_available = true;
    }
}

if (vehicle_available == false){
    return 0;
}

//record the whole vehicle file
String[] records_vehicle = new String[lineCounterVehicle];


reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(vehicle));

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    records_vehicle[i] = line;
    i++;
}
```

And this is me rewriting my file:

```java
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(vehicle, false);
for (i = 0; i < records_vehicle.length; i++) {
    String[] elements = records_vehicle[i].split(",");
    if (elements.length < 5) {
          elements = Arrays.copyOf(elements, 5);
    }
    if (elements[0].equals(carPlate)) {
        elements[3] = "0";
        elements[4] = salesPrice;
        writer.write(String.join(",", elements) + "\n");
    }
}
```

My file is CSV, which looks something like this:

```
carPlate,carModel,acquirePrice,carStatus,salesPrice
ABC123,Honda Civic,90000,0,95000
XYZ789,Toyota Camry,120000,0,126000
MNO456,Nissan Almera,80000,0,85600
PQR234,Mazda 3,110000,0,115600
GHI567,Ford Focus,100000,0,107620
JKL678,Chevrolet Cruze,95000,0,99750
STU901,Kia Forte,85000,0,89500
VWX234,Honda Accord,130000,0,147000
CDE345,Mitsubishi Lancer,90000,0,95550
FGH456,Nissan Sylphy,100000,0,105550
IJK567,Mazda 6,140000,0,148800
LMO678,Ford Fiesta,80000,0,85500
NOP789,Chevrolet Malibu,120000,0,127000
QRS901,Kia Optima,110000,0,113500
TUV012,Honda City,85000,0,89150
WXY123,Mitsubishi Attrage,75000,0,78050
ZAB234,Nissan Teana,130000,0,135400
CDF345,Mazda CX-5,150000,0,159900
GHI456,Ford Escape,140000,0,145670
JLM567,Chevrolet Captiva,130000,0,137000
MNO678,Ford Fiesta,80100,0,85000
PQR789,Chevrolet Malibu,121200,1,
```

I was expecting it to rewrite the file perfectly. While it did change the lines that I wanted to change just fine, for some reason it decides to just throw away random amounts of lines towards the end.

Comment: Oh and if you guys dont feel like reading the conditions, basically if the carPlate matches the one given, and its carStatus is 1, it will change carStatus to 0 and add a salesPrice, making it well, not null

Comment: Where do you close the writer? And are you sure that you close it? It needs to be flushed to write out the remaining parts held in the buffer, and so should either be explicitly flushed and closed or just closed.

Comment: Always use try-with-resources with streams

Comment: As @g00se mentions, if you use try-with-resources, then your writer is guaranteed to be closed.